# Changing color of gradient with transparent background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I have a logo composed of two colors with transparent Background. Colors going from one to another with gradient tool. How can I change those colors to different ones?
Here is the image:
[image]

I want logo colors to be from yellow on the top to blue on the bottom, and Image to still stay with transparent background and all antialiasing on the edges. I tried hue and saturation, but I cant make it to be clearly yellow to blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the PNG in Photoshop, and in the layers panel engage the Transparent Pixels Lock, shown highlighted red below

Create a new gradient using any colours you want.

[image]

Using  the new gradient you just made, click and drag using the Gradient Tool on the image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just apply a **Gradient Overlay Layer Style**...

[image]

By default, the Layer Style will honor existing transparency and may offer slightly more flexibility and a dynamic preview if you need to "tweak" things to a specific range.